# Variance of Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

> Consider $X_1$~normal(4,3) , $X_2$~normal(5,7), and $X_3$~normal(6,4), where $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ are independent. Obtain variance of $W = 2X_1 - X_2 + 3X_3 + 3.$

Attempt :

Since we are given $\sigma_1$ = 3, $\sigma_2$ = 7, and $\sigma_3$ = 4, we need to to do $\sigma^2_W = (2^2)(3^2) + (-1^2)(7^2) + (3^2)(4^2) = 229$

However, solution is 55. The solution does not square $\sigma_i$ values; I thought that since we're after the variance of W, we must also square standard deviation of each random variable; Why is this?

Comment: The notation ${\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ may help...

Comment: To me, $\text{normal}(a,b)$ means normal with mean $a$, **variance** $b$.   Some people use the same notation for mean $a$, standard deviation $b$. It looks as if the person setting the problem uses the same interpretation as mine. If the problem is from a book or notes, the meaning of the notation was almost certainly explained.

Comment: Yes. There seems to be an inconsistency. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general, if $X$ follows a normal distribution, then in shorthand it is written as
$$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2).$$
Thus, for example, the variance of $X_1$ is 3 **not** $3^2$. Or as you have written it
$$\sigma_1^2 = 3$$
**not** $\sigma_1 = 3$.

Comment: Is this the case with Gamma distribution, Binomial, Weilbull, Poisson?

Comment: @mathlover I do not understand, nobody chooses variance (or standard deviation) as a parameter of binomial distributions, say, so what are you asking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean since a typical distribution does not have the variance explicitly written into the shorthand. You'll have to deal with them on a case-by-case basis. For example, if $X\sim\text{Gamma}(r,\lambda)$, then the variance is $\frac{r}{\lambda^2}$.

Comment: sorry, disregard that question.